# Alternatives to using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a sp which takes input @featuretype. @featuretype will be equal to either "mobile", "login", or "index", and will correspond to a column in the db.

In my sp I have:

```
EXEC(
    'select TOP 3 * from featuredtypes_v where'+' featuredtypes_v.'+@featuretype+'Page=1'+
    ' order by featuredtypes_v.priority desc'
    )
```

However, I've been told this opens up the db to a sql injection. My two questions are, why is this, and how else can I write this query in order to avoid this?

Comment: Imagine `@featuretype` is `;drop table featuredtypes_v; --`

Comment: Bravo for dealing with this and not just sweeping it under the rug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you use `case`?

```
select TOP 3 * 
from featuredtypes_v F
where
    case
        when @featuretype = 'mobile' then F.MobilePage
        when @featuretype = 'login' then F.LoginPage
        when @featuretype = 'index' then F.IndexPage
    end
    = 1
```

Comment: +1 - I was working my way to this, but got sidetracked. Nice and clean

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure is open to injection if the user supplies the value passed into the variable, or if someone finds a way to execute the stored procedure passing in specially-crafted, malicious code.   Google my user name for an amusing comic based on this.

Since you're in a stored procedure, you can check the variable, and then do your `SELECT` statement based on the variable supplied:

```
IF @featuretype = 'mobile'
BEGIN
    select TOP 3 * 
    from featuredtypes_v 
    where featuredtypes_v.MobilePage=1
    order by featuredtypes_v.priority desc
END
IF @featuretype = 'login'
BEGIN
    select TOP 3 * 
    from featuredtypes_v 
    where featuredtypes_v.LoginPage=1
    order by featuredtypes_v.priority desc
END
-- etc...
```

Alternately, you can put the criteria in your `WHERE` clause in one query:

```
select TOP 3 * 
from featuredtypes_v 
where (featuredtypes_v.MobilePage=1 AND @featuretype = 'Mobile') OR 
    (featuredtypes_v.LoginPage=1 AND @featuretype = 'Login') OR
    (featuredtypes_v.IndexPage=1 AND @featuretype = 'Index')
order by featuredtypes_v.priority desc
```

Comment: The disadvantage to this approach is it doesn't reuse query execution plan, because execution may vary depending on parameters. This hurts execution, but it's safer than using dynamic sql.

Comment: @Nathan - yeah, I'm not really happy with this answer in hindsight, although I'll leave it up as a reference.  They *work*, but there are better, more obvious solutions, and I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be this. Make sure the column exists in the table, then execute dynamic sql, otherwise not.

```
if Exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'@featuretype'  
            and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tableName'))
begin

   EXEC(
    'select TOP 3 * from featuredtypes_v where'+' featuredtypes_v.'+@featuretype+'Page=1'+
    ' order by featuredtypes_v.priority desc'
    )

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You all not answering the quation guys. 
here is somthing sql injection could happend with

```
txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId");
txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + txtUserId;
```

now if txtUser = 105 OR 1=1 then the sql statment will be like this

```
SELECT UserId, Name, Password FROM Users WHERE UserId = 105 or 1=1;
```

you avoid sql Injection by using sql parameters. it validate the string and the sql execute alwaus like it suppose to